# The reduction of nilpotency order of nilpotent elements of $C^{*}$ algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Assume that $A$ is a unital  $C^{*}$-algebra. Let $a\in A$  be  a  nilpotent element with $$a^{k}=0,\;\;k>1.$$

> Are there two elements $x,y\in A$  with $a=xy,\;\;(yx)^{k-1}=0$?

Motivation for this question is described [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231328/the-saturation-of-murray-von-neumann-relation).

**Note:** The  above property can be  considered as  a ring theoretical invariant. It would be interesting to classify all unital rings with this property.